# WPF: When changing a ContentControl's Content, the new content object is NOT firing the loaded event

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, contentcontrol, datatemplateselector

**Problem:**

I am unable to hook into the point in time after I change a ContentControl's content, the DataTemplate from a DataTemplateSelector has been applied, and all visual layout has been completed, i.e. the new content is Loaded.

**Setup:**

A custom control called *'KeyboardHost'* which extends a *ContentControl*.

*ContentControl.Content* is bound (using a multi-binding) to 2 notification properties, via a value converter which combines the 2 bound properties into an object of type 'KeyboardCriteria'.

*'KeyboardCriteria'* is a public class, but I have also tried making this a FrameworkElement, Control and UserControl so that I could try to hook into the Initialized, Loaded etc events.

*ContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector* is a custom selector class (below) which returns a 
DataTemplate based on the ContentControl.Content (the 'KeyboardCriteria').

*The ContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector's DataTemplates are properties on the selector and are initialised and assigned in the resources section of my MainView.*

**Attempts:**

I have attached/overridden the following ContentControl events:

```
Initialized

Loaded

OnContentChanged

OnContentTemplateChanged
```

I have attached/override the following 'KeyboardCriteria' (defined as a FrameworkElement) events:

```
Initialized

Loaded

OnApplyTemplate

OnTemplateChanged

TemplateDP callback
```

**Observations:**

On startup:

```
KeyboardHost: OnTemplateChanged

KeyboardHost: ContentChanged

KeyboardCriteria: Initialized

KeyboardCriteria: Loaded
```

When changing one of the bound criteria properties (thus creating a new KeyboardCriteria object):

```
KeyboardHost: ContentChanged

KeyboardCriteria: Initialized
```

***N.B. The lack of a Loaded event on the ContentControl.Content object (the 'KeyboardCriteria').***

**Next steps:**

I think I will scrap the idea of using a DataTemplateSelector entirely and build the selection logic into my ContentControl, as this is already a CustomControl. I am hoping by manually creating the Content (and populating it) I can avoid the use of the DataTemplates that I currently use in the selection logic, as I suspect this is part of the problem.

...

***CODE SAMPLES:***

**MainViewModel:**

Exposes 'Keyboard' property, which initially has a non-null value.

**MainView:**

```
<controls:KeyboardHost Grid.Row="0" 
                       ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource KeyboardDataTemplateSelector}">
    <ContentControl.Content>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource KeyboardCriteriaValueConverter}" Mode="OneWay">
            <Binding Source="{x:Static properties:Settings.Default}" Path="Language" />
            <Binding Path="Keyboard" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </ContentControl.Content>
</controls:KeyboardHost>
```

**KeyboardCriteriaValueConverter:**

Convert method only, ConvertBack throws NotImplementedException.

Logic has been simplified to remove extra logic to check value types, count, etc.

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return new KeyboardCriteria
    {
        Language = values[0], 
        Keyboard = values[1]
    };
}
```

**KeyboardDataTemplateSelector:**

```
public class KeyboardDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    //TEMPLATE PROPERTIES HERE - THESE ARE SET IN THE RESOURCE DEFINITION

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var criteria = item as KeyboardCriteria;

        //LOGIC TO RETURN THE APPROPRIATE KEYBOARD DATA TEMPLATE BASED ON THE criteria
    }
}
```

*Thanks for any insight you can provide.*

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the entire post because I can't dedicate enough time/attention to read it at the moment, but the `ContentControl` will only fire `Loaded` once, when its `Loaded`.  What I found is that when you bind something to `Content`, the `DataContextChanged` event will get fired when the object bound to Content changes (and fires notification).

Comment: I'm happy that the ContentControl's Loaded event will not fire when the Content changes, but I am instead trying to get at the CONTENT's Loaded event. ContentControl.ContentChanged fires consistently, so I know when the content has changed, but I'm struggling to know when the new content has been loaded. I need to know when the layout pass has completed as my next step is to create a set of coordinates based on the rendered position of the new content and its child elements.

Comment: If I change the approach to not use data templates and a content data template selector (i.e. a content control which creates the content control and sets it on its own Content property) then the new content property correctly fires the Loaded event. I presume the original problem is something to do with the content not being a part of the visual tree, i.e. the KeyboardCriteria is templated and never ends up in the visual tree itself, so never fires a loaded event. I guess it is Initialized, then templated, and the templated elements fire the Loaded event themselves???

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I recently stumbled over the same problem.
Here is what I did, to solve it, in case someone else can use it.

After I set the Content of ContentControl i do the following:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, (Action)OnAfterRendered);
```

Then in the "OnAfterRendered" method i can work with the ContentControl with applied DataTemplates

Comment: I was struggling with the same issue. The approach suggested here by @Hogger actually worked, the only concern I have here if the invokation of the action here is time sensitive, and may it some times be called earlier than the selected template is applied, causing the action to run before the template is actually applied?